# No profile for team '<TEAM>' with ionic 3 run iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I try to build an ionic 3 app with push notifications. But when I run this command :

```
sudo ionic cordova run ios
```

I have this error :

```
Check dependencies
Code Signing Error: No profile for team '<TEAM>' matching '<APPPROFILE>' found:  Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching '<TEAM>/<APPPROFILE>'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.1'
```

**But I can deploy my app in XCode without problems ...**

I have configured my xcode like this :

[image]

First, I tried to use "Automatically manage signing" but I had another error.

I don't understand what I have to do with this :

```
Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor
```

I really need to deploy my project with command line to build with --prod for example.

Somebody have the solution ?

**UPDATE**

I don't understand why my Id team in my member ship details on the Apple Web Site and my 'TEAM' mentionned up, are differents ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try and specify those details in a [build.json](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/#using-buildjson) file in the root of your project. Then run the command you were trying before but with the `--buildConfig`.

`ionic cordova run ios --buildConfig build.json`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And what I have to do in the xcode project ?

Comment: Using the option above you shouldn't have to open Xcode. All the Cert. and provisioning profile info should be specified in that `build.json`.